# モバイル版の質問投稿ページで、タブのplaceholderの文字下部が切れている

Tags: バグ, 完了, タグ, デザイン, モバイル

モバイル版の質問投稿ページで、タブのplaceholderの文字下部が切れている。
具体的には「python go」の所。
使用ブラウザはSafari 7.1。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

このサイトのモバイル向けデザインは、[2018年のレスポンシブデザイン採用](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2783/3054)で大きく変わりました。よって、この問題をこのまま議論する必要も無くなったかと思います。

似た問題などがまた発生している場合は改めて報告いただければと思います。