# 日本語版を含む各ローカル版のレスポンシブ デザインがリリースされます

Tags: 討議, デザイン, 他言語サイトでの提案

この投稿は、@NicolasChabanovsky さんが Meta Stack Exchange に投稿された "[Responsive design for international sites will be released soon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315856/responsive-design-for-international-sites-will-be-released-soon)" の和訳です。

**本文**

**スタック・オーバーフロー 日本語版を含む各ローカル版は9月25日（火）に新しくレスポンシブ デザインに変わります。**

[先週、ベータサイトやその他サイトにて新しく外観のテーマが導入されました。](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315662/responsive-design-released-for-all-beta-undesigned-sites)

> 留意点：
>
> - 左側のナビゲーションはほとんどのページで有効です（ただし、サイトの設定にアクセスし、メニューより「折りたたむ」こともできます。[詳細はこちら](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16736/new-stock-theme-roll-out)）。
> - レスポンシブデザインはアクティブで、ページをスクロールせずにブラウザの幅に合わせてデザインを調整できます（一部のページはまだ更新されていません）。今のところ、スクロールを好む場合は、フッター内の「レスポンスを無効にする」リンクをクリックしてこの機能を無効にすることができます。
> - リンクのアンダーライニングがアクティブです。リンクをより目立たせるために現在強調されています。
>
> ...
>
> デザインの統一によって、 [タグのウォッチ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312180/favorite-tags-is-now-tag-watching)というような既存の機能をよりさらに改善したり、これまでにリクエストのあった、（現在テスト中の）[カスタム質問リスト](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312781/custom-question-lists-finding-questions-you-can-answer)などの新機能の開発を進めることができるようになります。
>
> 私たちは皆さんにより多くの機能を備えたいと思っています。現在60以上の異なるサイトデザインが存在し、それによるエラーを解消する時間を短くしたい、そしてその代わりに新しい機能に取り組むための時間にしたいと考えています。
>
> 詳細については、[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314799/why-we-initiated-the-latest-round-of-design-changes-and-the-role-of-meta)に書かれています。

Stack Exchange network の一部として、日本語版を含む各ローカル版はまもなく新しいテーマの外観に変わります。今回における違いは、各ローカル版にはテスト期間がないという点で、全てのユーザーがこのテーマを利用できるようになります。

エラーが見つかった場合は、この質問の回答にエラーを投稿してください。一般的な懸念などについては、[既存のMSE投稿](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness)にコメントを残してください。

各ローカル版からのフィードバックは[こちら](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315856/responsive-design-for-international-sites-will-be-released-soon)に投稿してください！

Comment: タグの「他言語サイトでの提案」は恐らく[他のメタ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2748/3060)での私の発言を採用して頂いたものだと思いますが、これは「(日本語版から見た)他の言語サイト」という意味合いです。一方でタイトルは「International Site」の翻訳かと思いますが、こちらは「主となる英語版**以外**の各翻訳版サイト」を指しているので、もっと別の表現、例えば「各国語版」「各ローカル版」等の方がよいのかなという気がします。

Comment: @cubick ありがとうございます、「各ローカル版」に修正いたしました。